# Angular js + Jekyll sample expressions not working

Tags: angularjs, jekyll

I have an angular js sample code, that is working nice on my localhost:

```
<span ng-bind="formData.name"></span>
```

but the expressions like this:

```
{{ 5 + 5 }}
```

or

```
The name is: {{ formData.name }}
```

NOT. What is the probleme here? I just copied this from the W3 site:

https://www.w3schools.com/angular/default.asp

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.formData = {"name":"asd", "mail":"mail", "message":"msg"};
...
```

Is it a probleme when I using JQUERY vs ANGULAR JS in one html file?

I am using Jekyll

Comment: can you provide your complete index.html file or plunker?

Comment: May be it is out of the angular application? Please, share your markup as Iacas asked.

Comment: Are you using any other template engine inside your project like handlebar (it treats {{}} to be processed by template engine) ??

Comment: Using Jekyll with angular js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either Angular is not bootstrapped properly or your html is not contained within a tag that has an angular module or controller associated with it. It may be because it's not loading for a variety of reasons such as a typo or invalid path to angular. You may be missing the ng-app="" on your first div. There are far better resources for angular than w3schools.com.

Answer (score 0):

Guys I think I got the solution:

http://alwayscoding.ca/momentos/2013/10/09/angular-and-liquid-expressions-in-jekyll/

```
app.config([
  '$interpolateProvider', function($interpolateProvider) {
    return $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{(').endSymbol(')}');
  }
]);
```